# How to center a ice:confirmationPanel within a modal ice:panelPopup (ICEfaces)?

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

If a (modal) ice:confirmationPanel within a modal ice:panelPopup is used, the confirmationPanel will not be centered; instead it seems to be centered relative to the panelPopups upper left edge.

This seems to be caused by the inline style of the panelPopup. It says `position: absolute`. Because it is rendered as inline style, I don't know how to change it to `position: fixed` which seems to solve the problem.

**Additional information:**
In my case it would be no solution to put the confirmation panel outside the panelPopup, because the confirmationPanel is part of a Facelets-Component (`ui:composition`). Whenever this component is used inside a panelPopup, this problem arises.

Any solution proposals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own popup component, which uses `position: fixed` divs instead of iframes - works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Just place the panelConfirmation outside the panelPopup. This way the confirmation panel will be centered, and it will be over the popup panel.

```
<ice:panelPopup autoCentre="true" modal="true" draggable="true">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <ice:panelGroup>
            <ice:outputText value="Edit" />
        </ice:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="body">
        <ice:panelGroup>
            <ice:commandLink value="Edit" panelConfirmation="editConfirm" actionListener="#{editor.edit}"/>
        </ice:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
</ice:panelPopup>
<ice:panelConfirmation id="editConfirm" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not a solution in my case. Please see my edits.